# Atomic operation involving separate processes

Tags: .net, process, atomic

I have two .NET applications I'm building which need to share a counter resource locally.  I'm looking for a way to atomically increment or decrement the counter from each application.

If I were doing this within a single, multi-threaded application, I would simply use one of the `System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment` and `System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement` overloads with a shared counter variable.

My applications will not have access to a database, so I can't use DBMS locking mechanisms.  Ideally, I'd like to use a registry `REG_DWORD` value, but I can't figure out a way to increment or decrement it atomically.  I've also considered having a file system folder where "incrementing" is putting a uniquely named file in the folder and "decrementing" is deleting a single file, but that seems a bit bulky or cumbersome of an approach.

Does anyone know of a good approach to this?

Comment: Use `Mutex` for interprocess synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a shared [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k(v=vs.110).aspx) to synchronize between multiple processes.

This allows you to "lock" and provide a guard around the code which accesses the registry, if that is the shared storage mechanism you choose to use.